# DocuSign API to find domain users

Tags: docusignapi

I have 1700 users who have registered to DocuSign using the company domain. These users are not part of the account. I am looking for an API to get more information on these users such as when they last logged in. I see there is an API available for getting users that are part of the ACCOUNT.

Users: List
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/users

As people who directly registered with my company domain email address don't have an account, I am not able to use this API. Let me know if there is any other API to get this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API that will give you this information. I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign support (or ask your DocuSign Sales Rep, if you've been working with one) for assistance -- it may be possible for them to provide this type of information for you.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I will follow up with DocuSign support.